# How to call Web service from C# client in Tibco BW

Tags: c#, web-services, tibco

Please tell me know, have a way call a web service from C# client in Tibco.

I had defined a process in Tibco Desiger but i don't know call it in C# client.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: have you created a Service or just a process definition?

Comment: I created web service through generate from process definition.

Answer (score 1):

Invoking a Web Service implemented in BusinessWorks from C# is exactly the same as invoking any other Web Service. The WSDL for the service can be found by clicking on the service resource that was create when generated the web service from the process definition, and selecting the "WSDL Source" tab.

One thing to note (which is often overlooked) is that you will need to set the SOAPAction header.

Also, to make it easier to debug the calls to the Web Service, you can create a process definition with a HTTP Receiver starter activity, that uses the same HTTP Shared Connection. Instead of starting the service in the tester, you can start the process definition. This allows you to see what is actually received by the engine, allowing you to tweak it until, the request URI, headers and post content are correct.

Comment: I want call a web service with paramater is object and then, it will return an other object. I use Send HTTP Respone but i don't find where to set an object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: When I save as content in "WSDL Source" tab, i save it as concrete WSDL file. How to use that file to call from C# client?

Comment: The same way you would call any web service from C#